# Understanding system naming convention in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, database-partitioning

As stated in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) names starting with `SYS_` and `ORA_` are used by the Oracle system:

> Oracle uses system-generated names beginning with `SYS_` for
>   implicitly generated schema objects and subobjects, and names
>   beginning with `ORA_` for some Oracle-supplied objects. Oracle
>   discourages you from using these prefixes in the names you explicitly
>   provide to your schema objects and subobjects to avoid possible
>   conflict in name resolution.

I'm currently working with an interval-partitioned table with partition names:

```
SYS_P2672
SYS_P1787
SYS_P654
```

Is there a convention according to which the integer in partition name *`SYS_`*`2627` is being generated? In particular, I would like to predict future partition names assuming that my partitions are generated by monthly or weekly intervals.

Comment: Although I cannot be 100% sure about this (to the best of my knowledge the algorithm the system uses to generate partition names is not documented) I think it's instructive to note that there is a sequence named `SYS.PARTITION_NAMES` whose NEXT value is always greater than the number used on any partition whose name was generated by the system, e.g. `SYS_Pnnnnn`. If I'm correct and this sequence is used by the system to generate unique partition names there's no way to predict the value that will be used.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks very much for your contribution. It's the best answer so far. Concerning predicting the next partition name, at least partially, the one can assume that it will have greatest number. So the newest partition is the one with the greatest number. I guess it's better than nothing.

Comment: Be careful about assuming anything based on those partition names. Export / import from another DB will copy the names of existing partitions, even if they 'break' the sequence. if there's the chance of data begin inserted for 'January 2018' before 'December 2017', the partition 'numbers' can get out of sequence again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use partition extended names and the data dictionary instead of relying on system names.

The partition extended name syntax allows SQL statements to reference partitions based on a value inside the partition instead of the actual partition name.

**Syntax:**

[image]

(There is also a similar SUBPARTITION version.)

**Example:**

```
--Create and populate sample schema.
--drop table test1;

create table test1(a date)
partition by range(a)
interval (numToDSInterval(1, 'DAY'))
(
    partition p1 values less than (date '2000-01-01')
);

insert into test1
select date '2000-01-01' + level
from dual
connect by level <= 100;

--Select the partition using a value.
select * from test1 partition for (date '2000-01-05');
```

If that doesn't work the partition information can be retrieved through the data dictionary.  This gets tricky, especially because the HIGH_VALUE is stored as text in a LONG column.  But it does allow complete control and automation when used in PL/SQL.

```
--Must create as a table to convert LONG to CLOB in SQL.
--(This would be easier in PL/SQL, you can just "TO_CHAR" it.)
create table temp_convert_long_to_lob as
select table_name, partition_name, to_lob(high_value) high_value
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name = 'TEST1';

--Show some data about the partitions.
select table_name, partition_name, to_char(high_value) high_value
from temp_convert_long_to_lob
order by partition_name;

TABLE_NAME   PARTITION_NAME   HIGH_VALUE
----------   --------------   ----------
TEST1        P1               TO_DATE(' 2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
TEST1        SYS_P3094        TO_DATE(' 2000-01-03 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
TEST1        SYS_P3095        TO_DATE(' 2000-01-04 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
TEST1        SYS_P3096        TO_DATE(' 2000-01-05 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')
```